# Is there any way for me to use ViewBag/ViewData property values as form input tag helper values? (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

In my controller, I have defined three different ViewBag properties.

```
ViewBag.Items = new String[] { "GroceryItem1", "GroceryItem2", ..., "GroceryItem25" };
ViewBag.Price = new String[] { "Price1", "Price2", ..., "Price25" };
ViewBag.Store = new String[] { "Store1", "Store2", ..., "Store25"};
```

All of the items in these arrays are objects in my Model.

For example,

```
[Required, Display(Name = "Grocery Item")]
public string GroceryItem1 { get; set; }
```

In my view, I want to have 75 input fields total - 25 for Grocery Items, 25 for Price, and 25 for Store.

Hardcoding 75 input tags and 75 span validation tags would be tedious, so I want to use a for loop and have the input/span fields inside of them, like so -

```
@for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++ {
     <input asp-for="@ViewBag.Items[i]" />
     <span asp-validation-for="@ViewBag.Items[i]"></span>

     <input asp-for="@ViewBag.Price[i]" />
     <span asp-validation-for="@ViewBag.Price[i]"></span>

     <input asp-for="@ViewBag.Store[i]" />
     <span asp-validation-for="@ViewBag.Store[i]"></span>
}
```

The code shown above is much cleaner and shorter than having 72 more input tags and 72 more span tags. However, it does not work. Any text being entered in the form fields are not saved in the model objects, and there is no validation being done.

I tried switching from ViewBag to ViewData in the controller and the View (with the proper syntax for that), but it didn't work either.

I am able to show the array contents inside a p, div, span, h1, or any tag, like so -

```
@for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++ {
     <p>@ViewBag.Items[i]</p>
     <p>@ViewBag.Price[i]</p>
     <p>@ViewBag.Store[i]</p>
}
```

How can I set the asp-for and asp-validation-for property values to the ViewBag/ViewData property values?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to correct your code a little. Instead of ViewBag use ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public string[] Items {get;set;}
 public string[] Prices {get;set;}
 public string[] Stores{get;set;}
}
```

and code you have to put in your Get action

```
var model= new ViewModel();
model.Items = new String[] { "GroceryItem1", "GroceryItem2", ..., "GroceryItem25" };
models.Prices = new String[] { "Price1", "Price2", ..., "Price25" };
model.Stores = new String[] { "Store1", "Store2", ..., "Store25"};

return View(model);
```

now view

```
@model ViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{    
    
... 

@for(int i = 0; i < @Model.Items.Length; i++ )
{
     <input asp-for="@Model.Items[i]" />
     <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Items[i]"></span>

     <input asp-for="@Model.Prices[i]" />
     <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Prices[i]"></span>
      ....
}
<input type="submit" value="Submit Data" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

and controller action

```
public IActionResult MyAction (ViewModel model)
{
     // your code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Where did you write the code for the ViewModel class? In the controller or the model?

Comment: @coderlover in your Get action, the same place where  was your ViewBag code I guess

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this is not working. The "asp-for" helper tag is being interpreted as a value tag and when the page first loads, all the input fields are filled with their corresponding model attribute (i.e. GroceryItem1, Price1). Furthermore, some of the form fields are date fields (I used grocery store as an example in my post for privacy reasons, but my actual form is something different) and there is no longer a date picker. There is no validation being done as well.  According to the Microsoft docs... (1/2)

Comment: "The asp-for attribute value is a ModelExpression and the right hand side of a lambda expression. Therefore, asp-for="Property1" becomes m => m.Property1 in the generated code which is why you don't need to prefix with Model. You can use the "@" character to start an inline expression and move before the m." https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-input-tag-helper     I do not believe that my asp-for value is being treated as a ModelExpression and is instead being interpreted as a normal string value. That is the issue I want to solve.

Comment: @coderlover continue to use a ViewBag then or  it would be better if you start to look for another profession. No assult, it is just a good advice for you from all my soul.

Comment: I think I will just have to hardcore all the form field values. ViewBag is not working and neither is ViewModel. Thanks for the help. and no, I don't think I will look for another profession.